# How to retrieve data from firebase based on some key's value which is in nested json object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this kind of structure in Firebase database for my post items.

```
"posts" : {
"-LP-UfzuUHFJOkY0Ogb9" : {
  "dislikeCount" : "0",
  "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/privato-dfb2c.appspot.com/o/images%2F2309fdab-0d78-44e5-af1f-8d256efdf6fd.jpg?alt=media&token=1276804f-d48c-4e06-8982-309fd539a397",
  "likeCount" : "0",
  "postByUser" : {
    "aboutMe" : "death is inevitable",
    "countryCode" : "+91",
    "imageUrl" : "https://i.imgur.com/hAazykl.jpg",
    "mobileNumber" : "number",
    "name" : "Sid",
    "userName" : "deathcode"
  },
  "timeStamp" : 1539754082148,
  "title" : "This is cool, lowest price ever on grocers.",
  "type" : 3
}
}
```

Now i need to retrieve all the posts made by certain user based on the value of userName under the json object object "postByUser".
I followed certain guides to resolve this but all of them worked on a json key value which was under the root post item, instead of under another json object under post item by using

```
 Query query = dbRef.child("posts").orderByChild("title").equalTo("sometitle");
```

but how do i use it for the nested json object?

Comment: Hey @SidhantRajora do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V or tick mark type looking button next to the answer, as this helps Stack overflow future readers and I'd appreciate that, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the sibling child values after using `orderByChild()` query and its `dataSnapshot`.

The code for this looks something like this:

```java
//ref is the correct database reference to your firebase database

ref.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userNameYouWant).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String aboutMe = ds.child("aboutMe").getValue(String.class);
        }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

You can retrieve other sibling node values using the same way.

Comment: Does not work, as child of posts has key to which i don't have reference,and cannot get the postedByUser and cannot filter the post by that

Comment: You don't need to have the key that is child of `posts` in your database for this code to work.

Comment: @SidhantRajora, you may read more about this here, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjp2-61z5TeAhUSKewKHRShAmEQFjABegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fdatabase%2Fadmin%2Fretrieve-data&usg=AOvVaw3srxM-1VFz8Ku8Yi61abEq

Comment: no it didn't worked so, i changed the structure of firebase data base.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a path to `orderByChild`, so:

```
Query query = dbRef.child("posts").orderByChild("postByUser/name").equalTo("deathcode");
```

Comment: post directly does not have postByUser/name as direct child

Comment: That's correct. Firebase database queries take each child node of the reference, and then find the property you specify in `orderByChild` for that node. Give it a try. :-)